# Sum of two matrices

Tags: python

I ran into an exercise, which I have a problem with:

Write a function with two input parameters: M1 and M2, those are arrays: list of list of numbers. Return the sum of the matrices if they are compatible, or an empty list otherwise.

For example:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] 
B = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]] 

matrix_sum(A, B)
```

You get:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

So I tried:

```
def matrix_sum(M1, M2):
    while len(M1)==len(M2):
        res = []
        for i in range(len(M1)):
            row = []
            for j in range(len(M1[0])):
                row.append(M1[i][j]+M2[i][j])
            res.append(row)
        return res
```

It works for some input but said:

Test failed for

```
matrix_sum([[1, 2], [2, 3]], [[4, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3]])
```

expected output: `[]`,
actual output: `[[5, 4], [3, 5]]`

How can I change it to work for this also?

Comment: If they're "matrices" (i.e. 2D), you can enforce a check `len(M1) == len(M2)` and `len(M1[0]) == len(M2[0])`, then cause the function to return `[]` immediately if either one of those tests fail.

Comment: That `while len(M1)==len(M2):` isn't useful. They're not going to change inside the loops (unless you've done something very wrong), and in fact you don't want to run the outer loop multiple times under any circumstances, so you probably just wanted `if`. (And, as @droooze pointed out, you just need to change the condition on it, and you're done.)

Answer (score 0):

Your function checks only that the quantities of rows match; it utterly ignores columns.  In fact, if you reverse the mismatched arguments, your function will crash on an index error.

Add another check:

```
if len(M1) == len(M2) and \
   len(M1[0]) == len(M2[0]):
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect the dimensions first, check if they're valid for element-wise addition, then carry out the addition.

```
def matrix_sum(M1, M2):
    dim_m1, dim_n1 = len(M1), len(M1[0])
    dim_m2, dim_n2 = len(M2), len(M2[0])

    if dim_m1 != dim_m2 or dim_n1 != dim_n2:
        return []

    res = [[0 for _ in range(dim_n1)] for _ in range(dim_m1)]
    for m in range(dim_m1):
        for n in range(dim_n1):
            res[m][n] = M1[m][n] + M2[m][n]
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (I tested it with your examples). It checks every secondry component:

```
def matrix_sum(M1, M2):
    comp=True
    n=0
    for i in M1:
        if len(i)!=len(M2[n]):
            comp=False
        n+=1
    output=[]
    if comp:
        n=0
        for i in M1:
            add=[]
            m=0
            for j in i:
                add.append(j+M2[n][m])
                m+=1
            n+=1
            output.append(add)
    return output
```